# No login screen on Ubuntu 12.10 after update

Tags: 12.10, updates, login, vmware, mesa

A few weeks back, I applied the latest updates to my Ubuntu 12.10 (32-bit) running Gnome-Shell, which happens to be a virtual machine running under VMware Player 5.0 on Windows 7.  After the updates and a subsequent reboot, I didn't get the login screen.  I could CTRL-ALT F1 to a text console, and I tried booting from the previous kernel, but no luck.

I discovered that if I disabled 3D acceleration in the VM settings, then the login screen would appear just fine. However, this isn't acceptable since the screen updates are just too slow.

I did a fresh install and after updating the same problem occurred.  The same problem does not happen on 12.04 LTS.  Not yet anyway.

I wrote a blog post describing the problem, and luckily someone left a comment that, although didn't directly fix my problem, helped me come up with a fix.  Here's a link to my post: http://www.itadmintools.com/2013/03/gnome-shell-just-broke-on-ubuntu-1210.html

The problem appears to be a bug in the 9.0.2 version of the mesa 3D drivers.  9.0.3 fixes the problem, and they are located in the proposed repository.

P.S. I would have written this in the existing question ([Ubuntu 12.10 no login screen after update (vmware workstation 9)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262402/ubuntu-12-10-no-login-screen-after-update-vmware-workstation-9)) but it was locked and I don't have the rating to unlock it.

Comment: Seems like it might be a problem with lightdm. Try installing gdm as an alternative to see if lightdm is causing the problem. From your console at Ctrl+Alt+F1, run this command: `sudo apt-get install gdm`

Comment: Nope, switching to gdm didn't help.